# Make element consume remaining space in a table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

In a table cell, I have 1 select element and 1 text input element. The select element can have fixed width set to 100px.

How can I make the text input to take up the rest of cell's width?

```
<td>
   <div>
      <select>
         <option>string</option>
         <option>integer</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text">
   </div>
</td>
```

[image: table cell with 2 controls]

Comment: As long as the table has a width, just use `width:100%` on the input.

Comment: Do you have a defined width for the table column?

Comment: no, the table is set to % width according to its container. The select's width can be set to 70px. The text input needs to take up the rest of the width. Is there any way to do it in css without using javascript to calculate the remaining width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to set the width of the input element.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 110px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select>
          <option>string</option>
          <option>integer</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the float properties:

```css
table {
  width:80%;/* for demo */
}
select {
  width:100px;
  float:left;/* start playing with float */
}
label {/* or whatever you choose to wrap input */
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;/* use a container turned into block to stand aside the float*/
}
input {
  width:100%;/* spread it all the way in avalaible space */
}
```

```html
<table><tr>
<td>
   <div>
      <select>
         <option>string</option>
         <option>integer</option>
      </select>
      <label>
        <input type="text"/>
     </label>
   </div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```